# Setting header file folders compiling opencv 3 on ubuntu 16

Tags: opencv, makefile, cmake, ubuntu-16.04

I'm having some trouble trying to compile opencv 3 in ubuntu 16. 
I've followed the [opencv tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/20/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-3-4-on-ubuntu/) and have gone over questions about the issue but can't make it work.

My problem is that compilation process doesn't find header files.
When I execute make -j4, the process finishes with the error.

/opencv/build/modules/freetype/precomp.hpp:61:22: fatal error: ft2build.h: file or directory doesn't exists
compilation terminated.

This file is located in following directories:

```
/xxx/tools/anaconda3/pkgs/freetype-2.5.5-1/include/freetype2/ft2build.h
/xxx/anaconda3/include/freetype2/ft2build.h
/home/xxx/anaconda3/envs/computervision/include/freetype2/ft2build.h
/usr/include/freetype2/ft2build.h
```

I tried to set the /user/include/freetype2 as header folder for make command with -I parameter but it didn't work:

```
make -j4 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz
```

Can anyone give me a hint about how to set the header folders?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solve it simply adding this parameter to cmake:

```
-D ENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF
```